# Different behaviour between 'npm run' command and windows console

Tags: node.js, batch-file, npm, electron, asar

Here's a weird problem I'm suffering for days.

I need to create an *asar* packed file, done with *electron* "*asar*" command, like this:

```
c:/asar pack app app.asar
```

That packs my "app" folder into a packed file "app.asar". Thats running OK.

**The goal**

I need to include this instruction inside my *package.json* script file in order to generate a build process, chainning other actions.

**The problem:**

Well, when I run this command, by package.json script like this `c:/npm run create-asar` or either with a `gulp-asar` process, it creates the *app.asar* file, but seems to be **corrupted**.

It can't be unpacked, process throws an error and can't be accessed by the electron app

[image]

I can't figure out why.

I've tried to run the exact same command from console, that in package.json, exactly the same, and both with the results above.

**what's the difference**?

**versions info**

- npm: v3.10.6
- node: v4.5.0
- asar: v0.13.0
- electron: v1.4.3

Comment: Perhaps you are encountering issue no. [74](https://github.com/electron/asar/issues/74) regarding _multibyte characters_ found in earlier versions. Try updating [asar](https://github.com/electron/asar) to a newer version. The issue was fixed in version [0.12.3](https://github.com/electron/asar/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0123---2016-08-29). Alternatively, If updating is not feasible, then check for any _multibyte characters_ in filenames/content and change them before the initial packing.

Comment: I'll try to update some packages, i'm using v0.13 on asar, but I'll give it a look.

Comment: still don't work. I'm going to update question with packages versions.

Comment: Then it's not a _multibyte character_ issue if you're running v0.13. Try installing `asar` as a project dependency. I.e. `cd` to to project directory, run `npm i -D asar` to add it to `devDependencies` in `package.json`.  Then update your npm-script  to `"create-asar": "node_modules/.bin/asar pack app app.asar"`. (Note `asar` is being run via the _node_modules_ _.bin_ folder). Then run `$ npm run create-asar` and see if it unpacks successfully.

Comment: @RobC with your instructions works! So it should be something related to another package, I'll try to figure what exactly it is, but feel free to post this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct as it's working like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Yes, it certainly seems like an issue related to another globally installed package, the `asar` package itself, or possibly a dependency conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [asar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asar) locally as a project dependency, `cd` to your project directory and run:

`$ npm install asar --save-dev`

Change your [npm-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to the following:

```json
"scripts": {
  "create-asar": "node_modules/.bin/asar pack app app.asar"
},
```

**Note:** `asar` is being executed via the local `node_modules/.bin` folder.

Then run `$ npm run create-asar` and subsequently check whether it unpacks successfully.

Comment: worked, so it may be something related to another package, or a globally installed package. Thanks mate.